# Change the order of Boot Drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 15.10

I have dual OS in my laptop, and I cannot change the order of their booting. As I start the laptop directly Windows opens. In order to use Ubuntu I need to keep pressing "esc and/or F9". How can I put it to boot using Ubuntu as default?

Comment: refer this [link](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-change-boot-order-set-default-boot-os-in-ubuntu-14-10-15-04-linux-mint-or-other-derivatives). The order doesnot change but the pointer can be changed according to your necessity.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without installing any additional software?

Comment: it is possible but it might be a complicated process

Answer (score 0):

Change the default operating system for startup (multiboot) within Windows

If you have more than one operating system installed on your computer, you can choose which one starts when you turn on your computer. More than one operating system installed on a computer is often called a multiboot configuration.

1. Open System by clicking the **Start** button, clicking **Control
   Panel**, clicking **System and Maintenance**, and then clicking
   **System**.
2. Click **Advanced System Settings**. If you are prompted for an
   administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide
   confirmation.
3. Click the **Advanced** tab, and then, under
   **Startup and Recovery**, click **Settings**.
4. Under **System startup**, in the **Default operating system** list,
   click the operating system that you want to use when you turn on or
   restart your computer.

*To be able to choose which operating system to use when you turn on your computer, make sure the **Time to display list of operating systems** check box is selected, and then click the number of seconds that you want the list of available operating systems displayed before the default operating system starts automatically.*

Comment: Do you mean to perform all these in Windows or DOS?

Comment: The steps are performed in Windows.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the help. I will try it the next time I use Windows and get back to you in case any.

Comment: And will also accept your answer if it works. Cheers...........